# Cannot find a way to search for " X or Y AND Z "

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api search post. I am unable to find the format in which query should be formed in the URL.

For example: I want to search for " X or Y AND Z "

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=X | Y AND Z&type=post

I tried above but not getting the correct post.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to url encode your request:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=X%20|%20Y%20AND%20Z&type=post
```